# Disable logging ip adress to access.log in lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, ip-address, filter

I have my webserver configured with lighttpd/1.4.31.

About 80% of all entries in lighttpd's

```
/var/log/lighttpd/access.log
```

consist of my own ip address.

I would like to disable my ip address logging access entries to access.log.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To clarify the question: You want to exclude all log entries including a certain IP address (e.g. yours)? First question: Why? Thats the task of logs: write everything that happens. For evaluations, it makes more sense to exclude certain IPs.

Comment: @sebix: Yes I want to disable logging my own ip address, because it makes analyzing logs more simple I think.

Comment: An easier way to not print log lines containing certain words is `grep -v '<ip>' <file>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling the accesslog-module using `lighty-enable-mod accesslog`, modify `conf-enabled/10-accesslog.conf` as follows:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_accesslog" )
accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "127.0.0.1" {
    accesslog.filename = "/dev/null"
}
```

---